# Is it possible call a custom function on another sheet of Spreadsheet on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I want to call a custom function of a spreadsheet A on a sheet of spreadsheet B, **wihtout the need to rewrite the other function that encapsulates the original custom function** defined in spreadsheet A. Is it possible for free? For example.

```js
  // function defined by Apps Script on Spreedsheet A
  function MYCUSTOMFUNCTIONA() {
    return `foo`;
  }
```

This function is recognized when I call `=MYCUSTOMFUNCTIONA()` on any sheet of spreadsheet A, but, if I want to use in any sheet of spreadsheet B, I have to include it as a library and encapsulate it in an another custom function, like this.

```js
  // suposing that I named the library as "spreadsheetA" to use it as a namespace
  function MYCUSTOMFUNCTIONA() {
    return spreadsheetA.MYCUSTOMFUNCTIONA();
  }
```

Comment: It looks that you have answered the question title. What is what you are really asking?

Comment: Sorry about that. I want to call the custom function (the first function) directely on sheet of another spreadsheet. I don't want to write a new custom function (the second function).

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is that you want other sheets to be able to use the custom functions quickly and without much action; then, you can try

> `Make a Copy`

### Details:

#### GAS

- go to [Apps Script](https://script.google.com/home)
- New Project

write the function, for example:

```
/**
 * @param {string} msg
 * @return {string}
 * @customfunction
 */
function Echo(msg) {
    return msg
}
```

and then:

```yaml
New deployment
Select type: Library
Write Description
click Deploy
go to Project Settings
Copy the "script ID" # something like: abc12_fjaidfjiasdjfiqoejasdfdas_JIJOIJOIJkasdfjajdfiojioB
```

- ❗ Share this project with others: (Include at least the authority to `viewr`)

```
General access: 
Click Anyone with the link
Set Role: Viewer
```

#### spreadsheet

- [Create a new spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets): New one
- Click `Extensions` -> `Apps Script`
- Click `Add the library`
- paste the `Script ID` and Add

I assume the Library that you added name is `MyLib`.

and you can write

```
/**
 * @param {string} msg
 * @return {string}
 * @customfunction
 */
function Echo(msg) {
    return MyLib.Echo(msg)
}
```

and then Save.

❗ Share the spreadsheet

```yaml
Anyone with the link: Set Viewer
Click settings⚙️(right upper corner)
[ ] Editors can change permissions and share
[V] Viewers and commenters can see the option to download, print, and copy # check this one
```

---

Finally you or someone else copies it(spreadsheet), they can use the function directly **without any further action** (please make sure they have permission to view the script)

### Example

here is an example:

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_kF011z34ARUM0vMofY2vt9LdkI8fCFE1dPqZWDFqUs/edit?usp=sharing

you can copy this, and try custom function: {`CountColItems`, `CountRangeItems`, `CountColItemsByGroup`}